# Does wearing a headband help for toothache?

Tags: medical-science

When I was a kid, comic books and specifically cartoon characters who had a toothache were always drawn with bandages around their head, usually knotted above the head.

What I want to know is whether or not there is any medical basis for this, or is it simply just a convenient method to visually depict that a character has a toothache? What is the reason for drawing them like this?

EDIT: Example of such a cartoon.
[image: Toothache]

Comment: Do you have any example comics?

Comment: @Oddthinking For instance: [Donald Duck](http://outducks.org/no/dd/1961/no_dd1961_17a_001.jpg) … more: [Google Image search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=toothache+comic&tbm=isch)

Comment: I've seen that too in old (e.g. 18th century) cartoons.

Comment: The question title made me think of this: http://moms4mom.com/questions/4761/has-anyone-used-amber-teething-necklaces but it's not strictly related.

Answer (score 7):

I think it was used to hold in place a poultice [[e.g.](http://www.oldtimeremedies.co.uk/2008/11/toothache-home-made-poultice-for.html)]
Such poultices could no longer be recommended where antibiotics and analgesics are available.

Alternatively, it may be being used to hold an ice-pack in place.There are plenty of examples of people getting the advice to use ice-packs on tooth pain: [[e.g.](http://www.ehow.com/how_2135033_manage-toothache-pain.html)]

Comment: Hmmm, I had actually forgotten about things like ice, but I didn't know that an old-time remedy was external poultices. Interesting.